# AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'tab'

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am searching the issue in this code but can't find it, may anyone guides me to the solution . Thanks !!!

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tab = [[[] for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)]
        
class Rtpt:
    def __init__(self, modele: Test, app: tk.Tk):
        self.modele = modele
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(app, width = 1000,
                                    height = 1000,
                                    highlightthickness = 0)
        self.canvas.pack()

        for y in range(100):
            for x in range(100):
                self.modele.tab[x][y] = self.canvas.create_rectangle((x*10,
                                            y*10, (x+1)*10,
                                            (y+1)*10), outline = "white", fill = "white")
                print(a)
    
def main():
    app = tk.Tk()
    app.wm_title("test")
    modele = Test
    rtpt = Rtpt(modele,app)
```

AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'tab'

Answer (score 2):

You never actually instantiated an instance of the `Test` class in your main function, thus throwing the AttributeError since the class itself has no attribute `tab`

Instead, call `modele=Test()` and it should work.